# General Approach to Update the Index for Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, kibana

A property for a query is not present in the current implementation of ES index. My task is I need to update the index of ES and I have no idea how/where will I start. For this problem, all I need is have a general knowledge/approach on this task since I am only new in this technology.

As of now I do not have any tried approaches since I am new on this task.

When the index is updated, this will be used in service (API/AWS Lambda) that consider the following factor: Performance, security

Comment: You will either want to create a new index and index all content to that new index which also contains that field, or re-index all the documents in that existing index, ensuring that those documents collide on ids and are replaced by the new documents containing this new field. Additionally, if you need any mapping beyond the default, make sure you assign a mapping to that field before doing the indexing.

Comment: Hi @Miek, when you say "Mapping to that field before doing the indexing" are you referring to its API side/ Lambda function? Please correct me if I'm wrong, since I am a newbie in these concept.

Comment: Referring to this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html